# Android storage permissions no longer work since Android 11 (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I need permission for my Unity Android app to be able to save a text file (I don't actually need to be able to read it). I have the code below to generate the popup that asks the user for permission. I noticed that it works on an older phone but not on a new one.

After some googling I realized that something is different from Android 11 onwards.
Unfortunately I haven't found anything that works for me on the internet.

Android Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Test.cs

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    bool hasPermission = Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead) && Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);

    if (!hasPermission) {
        Permission.RequestUserPermissions(new string[] { Permission.ExternalStorageRead, Permission.ExternalStorageWrite });
    }
#endif
```

I have already searched and tried on the internet, but nothing has worked. It should work on every Android version.

Comment: There is nothing special for permissions for Android 11. Only for Android 13+ you dont need those permissions any more.

Comment: Since Android 11 you should use Scoped Storage if you plan to release the app via Google Play. For scoped storage you have to rewrite all the fie handling code. There are a lot of examples online.

Comment: @Robert Do you have an example of this for Unity?

Comment: Most certainly you have to change only a few things. Depending on what you used to use. But that.. we dont know as you came not further than talking about permissions.

Comment: @blackapps I only want to download a single text file. This is generated by the app and should be saved in the download folder of the device. I do not need read permissions

Comment: You mean the public Download folder on external storage? Well your app can do that on Android 11 and 12 devices as soon as you obtained that WRITE permission.

Comment: Yes, I meant this folder.
The code described above works, but no longer as of the new version. However, I would like it to work on all devices

Comment: Furter: if your app generates a txt file then you do not have to download it from some internet server. So you can just save it then. And why in Download if you did not download the beast. Save in Documents directory and never talk about downloading again.

Comment: Saving with permission on Android 11 and 12 works. Can you confirm that? Any complains or problems about 13 and 14 devices? The code you posted you should not use there.

Comment: Let's continue writing in the chat